# Should URLs omit a parameter with the default value like ?page=1

Tags: seo, canonical-url, url-parameters

I have a blog and its URLs are paginated like

```
www.example.com/blog?page=x
```

I have pagination to create these links:

```
www.example.com/blog?page=1
www.example.com/blog?page=2
www.example.com/blog?page=3
```

But then I thought about making the `page=1` to be the default link without the page parameter like this

```
www.example.com/blog
www.example.com/blog?page=2
www.example.com/blog?page=3
```

The same goes for rewritten URLs like `www.example.com/blog/x`.  Should the first page be `/blog/` or `/blog/1`?

Which way is better for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs don't matter that much for SEO as long as your are consistent about it.   99% of the advantage of creating "SEO friendly" URLs is that it makes you think about what the URLs should be and makes you double check that you always use them the same way.

The worst thing that you can do for SEO with URLs is link to multiple versions of the URL that show the same content without doing any URL canonicalization.  So for page 1, all these URLs with probably work:

- `/blog`
- `/blog/`
- `/blog/?page=1`
- `/blog/1`
- `/blog/?page=1&tracking=xyz`
- `/blog/1?tracking=xyz`

You need to make sure that:

- You pick one of these URLs as your favorite "canonical" URL.
- Every time you link to your first page, you use your chosen version.
- If other versions of the URL get discovered by search engine crawlers you should use redirects, canonical link meta tags, or sitemaps to tell search engines about the preferred version.

Which specific version you choose doesn't matter much for SEO.  URLs don't seem to be much of a direct ranking signal to Google these days.   I see some very complex and not-user-friendly URLs ranking in Google when I search.

Even if it isn't a search engine ranking factor, you should pay attention to usability when you choose your URLs.   Your URLs should be:

- Descriptive
- Short
- Memorable
- Easy to type
- Consistent

That means that you should use the simplest version of the URL that conveys some meaning about the content of the page and is somewhat like your other URLs.    For page 1 I would go with `/blog/`, personally.

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters are not always a bad thing, and specifically page=x doesnt have any SEO disadvantage. In your case you would definitely want to go with your second option where the first (1) page would be simply: `/blog/` just looks more clean and helps user experience.

Google hates long parameters but likes the short clean ones that show the site's semantics and structure, which is your case.

You can also take a look [how to categorize parameters with parameters URL tool.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en)